# Fix a warning: [Camera] Attempted to change to mode Portrait with an unsupported device (BackDual)

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UICollectionView` with a `CameraCell` in it as a first cell, it displays a camera preview.

I want to fix a warning in XCode console on `iOS 16`, `iPhone XS Max` with dual rear camera:

```
[Camera] Attempted to change to mode Portrait with an unsupported device (BackDual). Auto device for both positions unsupported, returning Auto device for same position anyway (BackAuto).
```

It appears after `UICollectionViewCell` with camera preview is displayed on a screen (not when `CameraCell` is created). I tried to subclass `UIImagePickerController` and prevent any orientation changes - didn't help.

My `CameraCell` code:

```
final class CameraCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String {
        String(describing: CameraCell.self)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupView()
        NSLogIfDebug("[CameraCell] Init")
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit {
        NSLogIfDebug("[CameraCell] Deinit")
    }

    private lazy var imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController = {
        let imgPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imgPicker.delegate = self
        imgPicker.sourceType = .camera
        imgPicker.cameraDevice = .rear
        imgPicker.allowsEditing = false
        imgPicker.showsCameraControls = false
        imgPicker.cameraViewTransform = Constants.cameraViewTransform

        return imgPicker
    }()

    private lazy var cameraContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return view
    }()

    private lazy var cameraView: UIView = {
        // Used to return a dummy view on iPhone Simulator
        let isCameraDeviceAvailable = UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(UIImagePickerController.CameraDevice.rear)

        guard isCameraDeviceAvailable, let view = imagePickerController.view else {
            let dummyView = UIView(frame: .zero)
            dummyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return dummyView
        }
        
        view.frame = .zero
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return view
    }()

    private lazy var cameraImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .center
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.image = Constants.cameraImage
        imageView.backgroundColor = .surface8Color.withAlphaComponent(Constants.cameraImageViewAlpha)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return imageView
    }()
}

// MARK: - Private

private extension CameraCell {
    enum Constants {
        static let cameraImageViewAlpha = 0.4 as CGFloat
        static let cameraImage = UIImage(named: "photo-camera")
        static let cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.0, y: 2.0)
    }

    func setupView() {
        setupCameraContainerView()
    }

    func setupCameraContainerView() {
        addSubview(cameraContainerView)

        addConstraints([
            cameraContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            cameraContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            cameraContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            cameraContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])

        setupCameraView()
        setupCameraImageView()
    }

    func setupCameraView() {
        cameraContainerView.addSubview(cameraView)

        addConstraints([
            cameraView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraContainerView.leadingAnchor),
            cameraView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraContainerView.trailingAnchor),
            cameraView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraContainerView.topAnchor),
            cameraView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraContainerView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupCameraImageView() {
        cameraContainerView.addSubview(cameraImageView)

        addConstraints([
            cameraImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraContainerView.leadingAnchor),
            cameraImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraContainerView.trailingAnchor),
            cameraImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraContainerView.topAnchor),
            cameraImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraContainerView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

extension CameraCell: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {}

// MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate

extension CameraCell: UINavigationControllerDelegate {}
```

Comment: Hi Denis, any luck with this?

Comment: I had this problem! Setting 'Camera — Opt in for Portrait Effect' to NO in Info.plist fixed it!

Comment: I don't see this warning anymore in Xcode 14.3

Answer (score -3):

I had the similar issue with this warning.

```
2023-04-23 18:06:11.709709+0530 [19161:1003234] [Camera] Attempted to change to mode Portrait with an unsupported device (BackDual). Auto device for both positions unsupported, returning Auto device for same position anyway (BackAuto).
2023-04-23 18:06:12.445469+0530 [19161:1003512] XPC connection interrupted
2023-04-23 18:06:12.449248+0530 [19161:1003818] [Common] [SBSSystemServiceClient:0x2807805a0] Service suspended: the connection with the service host has been interrupted.
2023-04-23 18:06:12.449309+0530 [19161:1003752] [Common] [FBSOrientationObserverClient:0x2807a7180] Service suspended: the connection with the service host has been interrupted.
2023-04-23 18:06:13.190247+0530 [19161:1003524] [Common] [FBSOrientationObserverClient:0x2807a7180] Service suspended: the connection with the service host has been interrupted.
2023-04-23 18:06:13.190388+0530 [19161:1003524] [Common] [SBSSystemServiceClient:0x2807805a0] Service suspended: the connection with the service host has been interrupted.
2023-04-23 18:06:23.256350+0530 [19161:1003525] [connection] nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C11] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection
2023-04-23 18:06:23.256474+0530 [19161:1003525] [connection] nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint_block_invoke [C11] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection
2023-04-23 18:06:23.256551+0530 [19161:1003525] [connection] nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal_block_invoke [C11] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal on unconnected nw_connection
```

But this **solution works for me**
Info.plist has unwanted or extra keys.
In my case, I have this extra key, **delete that key** and everything working like charm! :)

[image]

Comment: It seems this is not a valid reason. It might have worked for you for some other reason.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey, yes possible. For me that was the reason. Are you facing the same problem? If yes what was solution for you?